# Fastest way to fill numpy array with random numbers

Tags: python, random, numpy, montecarlo

Is there a faster way to get a numpy array filled with random numbers than the built in `numpy.random.rand(count)` function? I know that the built in method is using the Mersenne Twister.

I would like to use numpy for monte carlo simulations, and fetching the random numbers is taking a significant portion of the time. A simple example, calculating pi by monte carlo integration with 200E6 random numbers is only processing about 116.8 MB/s through my program.  A comprable program written in C++ using xor128() as the generator processes several hundred MB/s.

EDIT: Miscalculated generation rate

Comment: generate to a file and load from there? not the best, but probably the easiest.

Comment: If all else fails you can always write your own random fill function in C or C++: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.how-to-extend.html

Comment: @Adam The problem with that is that I've had simulations run long enough to process hundreds of terabytes of data.

Comment: Are you timing the whole simulation, or just the random number generation? (If you're timing the random number generation, are both programs producing an entire array of numbers, or does the C++ code discard each number before producing the next?)

Comment: @user2357112 I am timing the entire simulation, but I can see from cProfile that the `random.rand` function is taking a lot of time. The C++ code buffers about 10000 numbers at a time. The python program operates on full sized arrays.

Comment: By adding a loop to the python program so that the each numpy array is smaller has increased speed. They are fairly comparable now, python=4.2 seconds, C++=3.38 seconds. Both performing at several hundred MB/s now.

Answer (score 3):

You could perhaps get a slight increase in performance by reducing the accuracy - if this is acceptable. I did this by using `randint` and scaling:

Using ipython `%%timeit`

```
count =1000

numpy.random.rand(count)

10000 loops, best of 3: 24.3us per loop

numpy.random.randint(0,1000,count)*0.001

10000 loops, best of 3: 21.4us per loop
```